# Linear Systems of Diff Eq - unsure how to solve

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, problem-solving, differential

here is the problem I am trying to solve: "Consider a system of two well-stirred and interconnected tanks that are filled to capacity. Tank 1 holds 40 liters of water, initially containing 20 kg of salt. Tank 2 also holds 40 liters of water, initially containing 15 kg of salt. Fresh water flows into tank 1 at a rate of 10 liters per minute, while salt solution flows out of tank 2 at the same rate of 10 liters per minute. Salt solution is pumped from tank 1 to tank 2 at the rate of 4 liters per minute and salt solution is pumped from tank 2 to tank 1 at the rate of 5 liters per minute. Find the amount of salt in each tank after 10 minutes. Round your answer to two decimal places." i was able to come up with the system of differential equations:

1. x' = 1/8y-1/10x
2. y'=1/10x-3/8y

But I'm unable to solve them. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: found solution on the internet [here](https://12000.org/tmp/solved_problems/dec_4_2023.pdf)